# create request with python requests (translation from another language to python)

Tags: python, api, paypal, python-requests

```
curl -v POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "CLIENT_ID:SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

This piece of code is from the api documentation. I can't figure out how to perform this action in python. Please help me to complete this query using python.

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/ translates automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple translation:

```
resp = requests.post(
    url="https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    auth=("CLIENT_ID", "SECRET"),
    data=b"grant_type=client_credentials",
    headers={
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
    },
)
resp.raise_for_status()
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me out! Incredibly grateful. Now, using your example, I will finally be able to work with the api) It's probably a shame not to understand such basics, but I'm just starting to work

Comment: You might want to just use one of Paypal's libraries instead. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/

Comment: Initially, I did this, but I was told that the Invoice API would be better suited for my purpose. My goal is just to issue invoices to receive money from customers. Give them a form of payment and receive money. Tell me, is the Invoice API really better suited for this, or do you still need to use the sdk library?

Comment: If you need the Invoicing API, then okay, it seems it doesn't have an SDK and you can just follow https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/basic-integration/